# Block URL's and Invalidate them

Tags: asp.net, security, iis, webforms

This is a valid url

**URL1:**

```
http://www.itsmywebsite.com/showproduct.aspx?id=127
http://www.itsmywebsite.com/browseproduct.aspx?catid=35
```

but this is not

**URL2:**

```
http://www.itsmywebsite.com/showproduct.aspx?id=-1%27
http://www.itsmywebsite.com/browseproduct.aspx?catid=-1%27
```

How can I block URL2 and the ones containing a string of format "-1%27" and invalidate the request. It's an automated bot sending this request so basically I want to just block the request in probably Global.asax? Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, those are both perfectly valid URLs. Your "URL2" is simply percent-encoded. Since 0x27 is an ASCII apostrophe, your percent-encoded URL2s are exactly the same as

- `http://www.itsmywebsite.com/showproduct.aspx?id=-1'`
- `http://www.itsmywebsite.com/browseproduct.aspx?catid=-1'`

Perhaps your web page should be validating the data it receives on the query string and throwing an error.

Comment: Wow never thought of that. Experience matters! How do I then block any url that starts with -1. The problem with handling these url's is my HealthMonitoring kicks in and my aspnet_WebEvent_Events table is full of "An unhandled exception has occurred." errors because of these url's

Answer (score 0):

Which version of iis are you using? If 7.0 or later use the URL rewrite module to reject invalid urls such as those ending in =-1

See an example blocking domains ( regex patterns ) here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BlockingImageHotlinkingLeechingAndEvilSploggersWithIISUrlRewrite.aspx